# Memory barriers - problems with linux headers

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, header-files

To understand better locks and semaphores I've started reading about memory barriers and built-in functions used to acquire and relase semantics and I've a simple multithreading program in C to test them, but the compiler can't find the headers.

`asm/system.h` no longer exists, I've found out `barrier.h` has to used instead, but in `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0.*/include` there's no `asm` directory and I've found `asm-generic` instead, and this one contains `atomic.h`, `atomic64.h`, `barrier.h`, `cmpxchg.h` and the other useful headers.

The point is that `asm-generic/atomic.h` try to include itself headers from `asm`:

```
> cat "/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-34/include/asm-generic/atomic.h"

#ifndef __ASM_GENERIC_ATOMIC_H
#define __ASM_GENERIC_ATOMIC_H

#include <asm/cmpxchg.h>
#include <asm/barrier.h>

#ifdef CONFIG_SMP

/* we can build all atomic primitives from cmpxchg */

#define ATOMIC_OP(op, c_op)                     \
static inline void atomic_##op(int i, atomic_t *v)          \
{                                   \
    int c, old;                         \
                                    \
    c = v->counter;                         \
    while ((old = cmpxchg(&v->counter, c, c c_op i)) != c)      \
        c = old;                        \
}
...
```

...and `barrier.h` try to include `linux/compiler.h` wich gcc can't find, even though `compiler.h` is actually in `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-34/include/linux`...

I don't understand why and how to make the compiler (GCC) recognizes the right path, in fact if I try to `#include <asm-generic/atomic.h>` it returns:

```
membarriers.c:9:32: fatal error: asm-generic/atomic.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 x64, Kenel version 4.2.0-34.

Suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to write a kernel module?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm try to understand barriers. I wrote a simple program where each thread do some operations on a shared var. Without barries, I saw, for example calling a thread function that only increment the critical var, that after thousands of loops the value is < than the loops. Now, I'm trying to use the built-in barriers function to acquire and release semantics correctly to do safe operations on this shared var, and I'd want to look at the disassembly to notice the differences. Later, I'd want to implement a mutex on my own. The point is the headers seem to be messed up.

Comment: Barriers won't make a difference. The issue with increments is interleaving of read/modify/write operations. Barriers don't fix that. In fact, if anything they'll make it worse by slowing the operations down and enlarging the race window.

Comment: If you want to experiment in user space, you should use a user space library like boost atomics or GCC intrinsics.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Why can't I use kernel defined mb(), rmb(), wrb()?

Comment: For the very reason that caused you to ask this question. They're just not hooked up that way.

Comment: Why are you set on using kernel routines? They are not for the weak of hearts. gcc provides a nice set of intrinsics to work with atomic - https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.5/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html